# Data not displayed after rows updated in Material Ui Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

This component is used to display the users. Once a new user is added from another component `usersUpdated` gets toggled and a call is made to backend to fetch all the users again which contains the newly added user and display in the Datagrid. But the datagrid does not display any record and distorts the datagrid UI. If the page is refreshed or some other action is performed in Datagrid like changing the pageSize displays all the records properly.

```
    const UsersDisplayTable = (props) => {

    const usersUpdated = props.usersUpdated;
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(
       [
                    {
                        field: 'email',
                        headerName: 'Email',
                        align: "left",
                        headerAlign: "left",
                        flex: 1,
                        filterable: true
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'dateOfBirth',
                        headerName: 'Date Of Birth',
                        align: "center",
                        headerAlign: "center",
                        flex: 0.75,
                        filterable: false,
                        sortable: false,
                        valueFormatter: (params) => {
                            const valueFormatted = moment(
                                    new Date(params.row.dateOfBirth)).format(
                                    'DD MMM YYYY');
                            return `${valueFormatted}`;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        field: "actions",
                        headerName: "Actions",
                        sortable: false,
                        filterable: false,
                        align: "center",
                        headerAlign: "center",
                        flex: 0.75,
                        renderCell: (params) => {
                            return (
                                    <>
                                        <EditUserIcon
                                                onClick={(e) => props.editUser(
                                                        e, params.row)}
                                                title='Edit'/>
                                    </>
                            );
                        }
                    }
                ]
    );

    const [allUsers, setAllUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get("/get-all-users")
        .then(data => {
            setAllUsers(data.data.data)
        }).catch(error => {})
    }, [usersUpdated])

    return (
            <>
                <DataGrid
                            sortingOrder={["desc", "asc"]}
                            rows={allUsers} columns={columns}
                            disableSelectionOnClick
                            disableColumnSelector />
            </>
    );
   }
   export default UsersDisplayTable;
```

Initial load of datagrid
[image]

after adding dynamic row or user
[image]

Is this a limitation of Material UI Datagrid?

Comment: It's a bug in DataGrid, using the version 4.0.0-alpha.32 will fix the problem.

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil I was using `"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.33"` downgrading to `"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.32"` did not make any difference...

Comment: interesting observation if i call the server after a timeout let's say 3 secs, the UI does not distorts and displays all updated rows

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue using @mui/x-data-grid version 5.0.1.

I was able to get around this issue by setting up a useEffect with a dependency on my rows. Within this use effect I just toggle a state variable which I use for the row height in my grid.

```
const [rowHeight, setRowHeight] = useState(28);    

useEffect(() => {
         if (rowHeight === 28) {
           setRowHeight(29);
         }else {
          setRowHeight(28);
         }
      }, [rows]);

...

<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  pageSize={pgSize}
  rowHeight={rowHeight}
  ...otherProps  
/>
```

I think by changing the height it's triggering a re-render of the grid and its contents.

This solution is a hack to work-around a bug in the code.

Comment: This useEffect would not work because it always considers the original value of rowHeight. It's not a dependency in your useEffect.

Answer (score 2):

For me setting the `autoHeight` prop to true fixed the issue:

```
  <DataGridPremium
   autoHeight={true}
    ....
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue on @mui/x-data-grid v5.17.14 (and Next.js 13 if that has anything to do with it)

In my case, the bug was when changing to a new page. I was pushing that change of page to the query params of the URL instead of using state, and then reading from there like this:

```
export default function usePagination(initialValues?:PaginationOptions) {
  const {query, push} = useRouter();
  const pageSize = Number(query.pageSize) > 0 ? Number(query.pageSize) : initialValues?.initialPageSize ?? GLOBAL_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
  const page = Number(query.page) > 0 ? Number(query.page) : initialValues?.initialPage ?? 1;
  const setPage = (input:number) => push({query:{...query, page:input+1}});
  const setPageSize = (input:number) => push({query:{...query, pageSize:input}});
  return {page, pageSize, setPage, setPageSize};
}
```

That doesn't work because datagrid must somehow be checking which parameter caused the re-render, and since this change was coming from a change in URL, it didn't react properly.

Forcing to use a `useState` for the page fixes the issue:

```
export default function usePagination(initialValues?:PaginationOptions) {
  const {query, push} = useRouter();
  const pageSize = Number(query.pageSize) > 0 ? Number(query.pageSize) : initialValues?.initialPageSize ?? GLOBAL_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
  const [page,setPageState] = useState(Number(query.page) > 0 ? Number(query.page) : initialValues?.initialPage ?? 1);
  const setPage = (input:number) => {setPageState(input+1); push({query:{...query, page:input+1}})};
  const setPageSize = (input:number) => push({query:{...query, pageSize:input}});
  return {page, pageSize, setPage, setPageSize};
}
```